# Script works inline but when i move to external doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just made a script for my navigation. So that it becomes a sticky navigation once it is scrolled to the top.

It works great when i have it at the bottom of my index file via `<script>` tags but when i try to place it in an external js file it doesnt seam to fire at all.

**[Full Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zwyL496/)**

**Heres the script:**

```
var windw = this;
$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);
    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: "20px"
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: '0',
                left: '0', right:'0',
                top: 'inherit'

            });

        }
    });

};
$('#mainNav').followTo( $(window).height() - ( $('#mainNav').innerHeight() + $('.globalHeader').innerHeight() ));
```

Comment: The fiddle is empty, and also tell us that how you link the external file with your HTML file.

Comment: Include your external js file _at the bottom of index file_

Comment: @ maihan Nijat @Rayon Dabre  I fixed the link. Sorry about that guys. And ive tried the suggestions you made before with no luck. please have a looksie at the fiddle now that i saved it.

Comment: Look into the browser's console. Also add the HTML code of the index file.

Comment: Fiddle link updated @Charlotte Dunois

Comment: You need to include jquery i've included it Here https://jsfiddle.net/gw3m7wfu/  and the code works fine.

Comment: Thanks so much @AntonioSmoljan How did you add it to the fiddle if u dont mind me asking? 

Can you post this as the solution via an answer please. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jQuery` library is missing you must add it above the external script. In the fiddle example click the `javascript` text in the upper right corner of the javascript code tab and choose a jquery version from the frameworks

Comment: Glad it helped keep it at it :D